# Backquote in string template?

Tags: string-manipulation, templates

I need to have backquotes in a `StringTemplate`.

For example

```
StringTemplate["``1``"][2]
```

Returns `"21"` instead of `` "`2`" ``.

How can I get the correct result ?

Of course a solution would be to use another character than the backquote and replace it after but this is not elegant.

Comment: Would escaping the first and last back ticks by preceding them with a backslash work? Unfortunately I'm on a tablet and can't check for myself.

Comment: No it doesn't I've tried.

Comment: Another kludge: ```StringTemplate["`1``2``1`"]["`", 2]```

Comment: Yes, it's the same idea as Kuba in ```TemplateApply["`a``input``a`", <|"a" -> "`", "input" -> 2|>]```. I think it's the easiest and most flexible answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**edit**

One can use template expression too:

```
StringTemplate["<*\"`\"*>``<*\"`\"*>"][123]
```

> ```
> "`123`"
> ```

---

**old answer**

That's unfortunate design/coincidence, the more that accents are important part of package files. What I'm using is an additional `` "`a`" `` which later is part of input `` <|"a"->"`", ...|> ``.

So at the end I'd go with

```
TemplateApply["`a``input``a`", <|"a" -> "`", "input" -> 2|>]
```

> ```
> "`2`"
> ```

quite ugly, but in case of file full of accents, like a package, works well.

Other way is to choose a character that is not going to appear there ever and replace it with accent:

```
StringTemplate[
   "\[FormalA]`1`\[FormalA]", 
   CombinerFunction -> (StringReplace[StringJoin@#, "\[FormalA]" -> "`"] &)
][2]
```

Comment: "Of course a solution would be to use another character than the backquote and replace it after but this is not elegant." - quoted from the question :)

Comment: @eldo still, the first suggestion is different enough (I hope ;)) I decided to post it ;)

Comment: Ok so it seems I'm not missing anything, it's more a design issue. Hopefully it will be solved at some point. I could do any ad hoc solution, this is not the problem, it's more that I wanted to be sure there isn't an elegant solution to the problem, like a simple escape of the backquote.

Comment: I think your first suggestion is the most practical.

Comment: @faysou thanks, p.s. something new came to my mind, take a look at the edit.

Comment: indeed this would be the real way to escape, but I still prefer your answer with `a`, it makes the template easier to understand, and this is what matters.

Answer (score 5):

You could build your own `TemplateObject` instead of relying on `StringTemplate` to do that:

```
template = TemplateObject[
     {"`", TemplateSlot[1], "`"},
     CombinerFunction -> StringJoin,
     InsertionFunction -> ToString
   ];

template["hello"]
template[4]

(* Out:
"`hello`"
"`4`"
*)
```

This does not require any substitution after-the-fact. In this most recent iteration I have added the `InsertionFunction -> ToString` bit, as suggested by @AlbertRetey in [his comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101342/backquote-in-string-template/101347?noredirect=1#comment275003_101347): this allows the template to handle numerical input as well as strings.

Comment: I really like this one. If you add `InsertFunction->ToString` the OPs example with a number will also work.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Thank you! That's an excellent point you made about `InsertionFunction`; I added that to my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way seems to be to use the `InsertionFunction` option to add the additional backquotes in:

```
    StringTemplate["`1`", InsertionFunction -> ("`" <> ToString[#] <> "`" &)][2]
```

Returns

```
    "`2`"
```

Comment: This wouldn't work in a real case with several arguments as I wouldn't want to put backquotes everywhere. I'm looking for a way to escape the backquote character.

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative based on the syntax

```
StringTemplate["`1`"]["`2`"]
(* "`2`" *)
```

would be to use the function

```
stringTemplate[string_][seq___] := 
   StringTemplate[string][## & @@ ("`" <> ToString[#] <> "`" & /@ {seq})]
```

For instance, considering the first example of `StringTemplate` in the documentation

```
stringTemplate["The orbit of `1` has period `2`."]
              ["Jupiter", Quantity[11.8707, "Years"]]

(* "The orbit of `Jupiter` has period `11.8707 years`." *)
```

Comment: That's clever, but it doesn't work if you need to insert an argument inside backquotes. For example ``planet` is heavy`

Comment: "``Jupiter` is heavy`" as output

Comment: I've encountered such problems by building SQL queries where backquotes are necessary sometimes.