# How to include a backquote in a message?

Tags: string-manipulation, message-coding

**NB:** I know one suboptimal solution to this problem, which I give at the end.  I'm looking for a better one.  Also, I was not able to solve this problem with the solutions give in [Backquote in string template?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101342/2464).

---

For example, this assignment is no problem:

```
example::message = "foo`bar is set to `1`"; (* no problem *)
```

But if one uses this message in a `Message` expression, then two messages appear, and the second one is malformed:

```
foo`bar = 3;
Message[example::message, foo`bar]
```

> ```
> StringForm::sfq: Unmatched backquote in foo`bar is set to `1`. >>
> example::message: foo`bar is set to `1`
> ```

---

One solution is to make a slot for the backquote, and include `` "`" `` among the message parameters:

```
example::message = "foo`1`bar is set to `2`";
Message[example::message, "`", foo`bar]
```

> ```
> example::message: foo`bar is set to 3
> ```

This solution, however, is suboptimal, because it requires users to remember to include the otherwise meaningless "`" among the message parameters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [`StringForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringForm.html#DetailsAndOptions) docs use `` "`.`" ``:

```
m::a = "`1` `.` `2`";
Message[m::a, "a", "b"]

m::a: a ` b
```

Comment: wonder why `StringTemplate` doesn't use this convention.

Comment: @george2079 `Message` uses `StringForm` which is just a formatting head. But it's a much more restricted system. In `StringTemplate` you could match that "`.`" to `"."` in your template driver so it introduces ambiguity.